# How to index table column of specific database with code in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I want to write code to index the column of a specific database table column.
Iam trying in this way

```
DB::connection('mysql2')->raw("ALTER TABLE `consignments` DROP INDEX customer_reference");
```

What is correct method for this process

Comment: Do you need to add or remove (drop) the index on the table?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Laravel migrations, see this documentation:

[Laravel Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations)

[Laravel Migrations/Index related](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#creating-indexes)

You can execute this command in the shell on the project path and edit the created file in the database/migration path and add the index for the column following the documentation

```
php artisan make:migration add_index_to_consignments_table
```

Or create manually a file in the database/migrations path with a name like this:
2021_07_29_022532_add_index_to_consignments_table.php and copy/paste this php content

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddIndexToConsignmentsTable extends Migration
{

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('consignments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //Uncomment one line depending on what you need
            //$table->index('customer_reference'); //If you need  to add an index
            //$table->dropIndex('name_of_index_on_table'); //If you need to remove an index
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('consignments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //Uncomment one line depending on what you need
            //$table->dropIndex('name_of_index_on_table'); //If you need  to add an index
            //$table->index('customer_reference'); //If you need to remove an index
        });
    }

}
```

After creating the file with any method you have to execute this command in the shell on the project path:

```
php artisan migrate
```